# Why scope value can't be changed from HTML by using "switch" technique?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have simple controller code:

**JS**

```
$scope.showErrorAlert = false;


$scope.switchBool = function(value) {
    value = !value;
};
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="alert alert-error" ng-show="showErrorAlert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-ng-click="switchBool(showErrorAlert)" >×</button>
              <strong>Error!</strong> {{errorTextAlert}}
             </div>
```

From snippets of code you can see that I try to change `$scope.showErrorAlert` value.

However it doesn't work, `value` changes but not `showErrorAlert`.

Can anybody tell me why and how to make it work, please?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Others already gave you a proper answer on why the passed variable is not changed on scope. But if your real use-case is just to toggle the boolean value than there are at least two other simpler ways of accomplishing that:

a) Toggle the variable directly inside the ngClick expression:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="showErrorAlert = !showErrorAlert">×</button>
```

b) Toggle the variable by passing the variable name to a generic "switch" function:

```html
<button type="button" ng-click="switchBool('showErrorAlert')">×</button>
```

```js
$scope.switchBool = function(var){
  $scope[var] = !$scope[var];
};
```

Answer (score 6):

JS passes parameters by value. A simple substitute for pass by reference is to pass an object (as opposed to the property itself).

I.e.

```
$scope.showErrorAlert = { value: false };

$scope.switchBool = function(obj) {
    obj.value = !obj.value;
};
```

Or you might refactor the switchBool code to operate on $scope itself. You need to hardcode or abstract "showErrorAlert" then, tough. Depends on your requirements.

Comment: no need to declare new Object syntax just use $scope.showErrorAlert= {value:false}

Answer (score 2):

```
$scope.showErrorAlert = false;


$scope.switchBool = function(value) {
    value = !value;
};
```

When you pass a value to `switchBool`, it is passed by value, not reference. So the value is only changed within that function.

You could try passing it the var name, like `$scope.showErrorAlert` and then do something like this within `switchBool`:

```
eval(value + " = !" + value);
```

in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Npp2N/1/

```
$scope.showErrorAlert = false;
$scope.switchBool = function(value) {
    eval(value + " = !" + value);
};

console.log($scope.showErrorAlert); // false
$scope.switchBool("$scope.showErrorAlert");
console.log($scope.showErrorAlert); // true
```